# scope.$watch() is not triggered after enter key press nor location.path is working

Tags: javascript, angularjs

There is a strange issue I am facing with angular js. Let me explain...

I am using scope.watch to watch the text changes in text field (searchloco)

```
<input class="typeahead"  ng-model="searchloco" data="{{varu}}" search-bar   type="text">
```

I am also using keydown function to detect enter key press and what I need is to change location.Path on Enter key press.

But when I type any key (not enter) it works fine i.e it is getting text update in watch as well as keydown function is also working fine.When I hit Enter key, keypress event does fire but watch cycle does not work for this key neither the statement "Location.path("/") is working , which is just below the if statement which confirms that it was a 'enter' key , until or unless I type another key(a-z).

```
 element.on( 'keydown' , function (e){
            console.log("=== key down pressed === ",e);
            if(e.which == 13){
                location.path('/search/');
                 ...
                 ...
```

Not sure if I could explain the issue so that it is easy to understand so let me know if I need to explain more.

Comment: There are a lot of fundamental issues with this code - if your using a typeahead can I suggests using angular bootstrap and not try to roll your own. Also as stated use angular services such as $location or $log and inject them into your controller  - there is a lot of documentation and resources out there to help.

Comment: Just a note: usually the enter key will not trigger the `$watch` callback because the model hasn't changed per se as *enter* in a text input doesn't elicit the same change as it would in a textarea.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll likely need to wrap the code in your callback in a [$scope.$apply()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply), like so:

```
element.on( 'keydown' , function (e){
    $scope.$apply(function () {
        console.log("=== key down pressed === ",e);
        if (e.which == 13){
            location.path('/search/');
        }
    });
});
```

### ng-keydown

However the suggested "angular way" to do this is to use an [ng-keydown](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngKeyup#!) directive instead of doing a jQuery-style element.on().

HTML:

```
<input class="typeahead" ng-keydown="keypress" ng-model="searchloco" data="{{varu}}" search-bar type="text">
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.keypress = function ($event){
     console.log("=== key down pressed === ", $event);
     if ($event.which == 13){
         location.path('/search/');
     }
});
```

### ng-submit

Ideally though, you will probably want to wrap the input field in a form and then handle the [ng-submit](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSubmit). This should handle hitting the enter key in a less platform-dependent manner.

```
<form ng-submit="go">
    <input class="typeahead" ng-model="searchloco" data="{{varu}}" search-bar type="text">
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$scope.go = function (){
     location.path('/search/');
});
```

Comment: I really like you ng-submit suggestion... while it's not angular-ish, it is the most framework agnostic and reusable.

Comment: Interesting, what to you is less angular-ish about it? I can say that I wish the state of the form was somehow passed as an argument to the submit callback, but this is more of a general code structure concern than an angular concern.

Comment: Maybe I should have said less angular-ish.  If I understand your comment, In terms of submitting the state of the form to the submit callback, you can access within the callback via the `$scope`.  Give the form and the inputs a name.  The form directive uses the name on the DOM element to attach to the $scope/controller, so for `<form name="myForm">`, you can access via `$scope.myForm`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try injecting $location and doing `$location.path('/search/');`?

Comment: $location is an Angular wrapper for window.location (you are trying to use window.location.path). Off hand, I don't see any reason it wouldn't work - I always use $location.path() successfully when I need to force a simple navigation.